# iCloud application back-up size

Tags: ios, icloud

I was wondering if there is a limit to the size of an iOS application back-up on iCloud (the application doesn't use iCloud to save progress).My app makes a back-up of 1.1 MB. I asked some friends and some of them told me that the limit is 1 MB others told me that the limit is 36 MB. Could you guys help me figure this one up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limit on iCloud,
I am providing a link below you can get more details from there
https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204247